# Is there a pattern to validate if a phone number is of a concrete country?

Tags: android, pattern-matching, phone-number

I want to know if there is any default pattern to validate if a phone number is of a concrete country?

Currently, I am using a `Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phone).matches();` but this validates a phone, no an EEUU phone, Italy phone, etc...

How can do for know if the telephone number is a number of a concrete country? And is it possible to do without the international prefix like +0012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) library from Google

```
implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.8.5'
```

**code**

```
  PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.createInstance(this)
  PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse("+917874962727", null)
  String regionCode = phoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForNumber(phoneNumber) // IN for India
```

*getRegionCodeForNumber* will give you country code. further, you can map like

- US => USA
- IN => India
- IT => Italy